# Offset binary format for float in java

Tags: java, binary, floating-point, offset

when i am looking at the [wikipedia page for Offset Binary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_binary), i cant follow the following sentence:

> Unusually however, instead of using "excess 2^(n-1)" it uses "excess
>   2^(n-1)-1" which means that inverting the leading (high-order) bit of
>   the exponent will not convert the exponent to correct twos' complement
>   notation.

can anyone explain it in details and give me some examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the range of exponents which allows you to calculate 1/Float.MAX_VALUE and 1/Float.MIN_NORMAL without going to zero or Infinity. If there was one more negative exponent and one less positive exponent, (with an offset of 128) 1/Float.MIN_NORMAL would be Infinity.

---

The exponent in floating point is offset rather than plain two-complement.

e.g. for `double` a 0 exponent is 11-bit value for 1023 or 0b0111111111, -1 is 1022 or 0b0111111110, +1 is 1024 0b10000000000.

In twos-complement, the number would be 0 is 0b00000000000, -1 is 0b11111111111, and +1 is 0b00000000001

A property of using an offset, is that the maximum is half the possible number of values. i.e. for 11 bits the range is -1023 to 1024 instead of -1024 to 1023.

Another property is that number can be compared by just comparing the integer values.

i.e.

```
long l1 = Double.doubleToRawLongBits(d1);
long l2 = Double.doubleToRawLongBits(d2);
if (l1 > l2) // like d1 > d2
```

The only difference is in the handling of NaN and -0.0  The approach Double.compare(double, double) uses is based on this.

Comment: thanks but your answer is actually not what i want.i want to know,such as float, why the offset is not 2^(n-1)=128 but 2^(n-1)- 1 =127

Comment: I am just guessing but I have added what I think could be the thinking.